# How to format date displayed in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datatables, isodate

I have a function that displays objects in my array using datatables. I'm a bit a problem with changing the date and time format from ISODate to human readable format.

**myData**

```
var datas = {“rows” : [{_id: "2017-01-03T00:00:00.000Z", Humidity: 24, Temperature: 18},

{_id: "2017-01-04T00:00:00.000Z", Humidity: 23.071428571428573, Temperature: 18.928571428571427} ]}
```

**JS script**

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( { 
    data: datas.rows,
            "columns": [
                { data: "_id" },
                { data: "Temperature" },
                { data: "Humidity" }

            ]
    });
```

Thanks for your anticipated help.

Comment: What does human-readable means precisely in your case?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render to change how values are displayed, and http://momentjs.com/ would be helpful to get the date in the format you want.

Comment: @kraskevich YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM that what i mean.

Comment: @PaulAbbott thanks for the link. I have 3 columns but I only want to render one. Does the render function come immediately after the specific column or do I add it at the end of the `{data: "Humidity"}` ??

Comment: @PaulAbbott Can you show me an example of how I can construct this? The link didn't give me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As noted by @Paul Abbott above, momentjs and a render function should see you right:

```
var datas = {
    "rows": [
        {
            _id: "2017-01-03T00:00:00.000Z", 
            Humidity: 24, 
            Temperature: 18
        },
        {
            _id: "2017-01-04T00:00:00.000Z", 
            Humidity: 23.071428571428573, 
            Temperature: 18.928571428571427
        } 
    ]
}


var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( { 
    data: datas.rows,
    "columns": [
        { 
            data: "_id",
            render: function(data, type, row){
                if(type === "sort" || type === "type"){
                    return data;
                }
                return moment(data).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm");
            }
        },
        { 
            data: "Temperature" 
        },
        { 
            data: "Humidity" 
        }

    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm getting an error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.fn.dataTable.render')`. Although I included the datetime cdn in my HTML file.

Comment: Apparently my scripts weren't in order but i'm still getting an error `moment is not a function`

Comment: Without being able to see your script I can't tell what's going on. This is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/hpgafeys/. You'll need to include, in this order, jQuery, DataTables and MomentJS.

Comment: Thank you! I keep getting `moment is not a function`. Could this because i'm not loading the scripts in the right order?

Comment: Quite possibly. Did you check the Fiddle? Do you want to put your script up on JSFiddle so we can check it together?

Comment: @annoyingmosuse Yes I did. I think I see what I was missing. I didn't include the `moment with locales` script.

Comment: Thank you so much @annoyingmouse. This is a bit of scope but is there a way I can round up figures in the table?

Comment: Of course, again use a render function and this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: I just figured the dates are a bit off. The table produces dates a day before the actual date. See your jsfiddle. A bug maybe?

Comment: Not an issue for me, I'm getting the 3rd and 4th. The dates are in UTC, it might be because you're in a different region?

Comment: Okay that's a bit odd. I have used different date formats getting the same thing.

Comment: This essentially kills the sorting feature

Comment: @Sandor, just added some more dates with more varied values and I'm able to sort... what's is your particular issue? https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/hpgafeys/

Comment: @annoyingmouse please see [https://jsfiddle.net/ca8w78y1/](https://jsfiddle.net/ca8w78y1/) for reference

Comment: @Sandor, I stand corrected - does this do what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/cgqqLaw1/

Comment: @annoyingmouse: mea culpa, the _if(type === "sort" || type === "type")_ did the trick however please be aware that there is an error in the answer since the _function(d)_ definition instead of _function (data, type, row)_