# How to display only date part of date time in jQuery data-table

Tags: jquery, datatables, datetime-format

I am using `jquery` `data-table`. I want to show only date instead of complete date time in `jquery` `data-table` my sample code as below.

```
$(".example").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/FiscalYear/Get",
                "type": "Get",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            responsive: true,
            "columns": [
                 { "data": "fiscalYearStart", "name": "fiscalYearStart", "width": "40%"  },
                 { "data": "fiscalYearEnd", "name": "fiscalYearEnd", "width": "40%" },
                 { "data": "fiscalYearFor", "name": "fiscalYearFor", "width": "10%" }
             ],
             "serverSide": "true",
             "processing": "true",
             "language": {
                 "processing": "Loading data..."
             }
        });
```

Date display as `2015-07-01T00:00:00`, but I wish date should display as `2015-07-01`

Comment: Try using the `momentjs` library it's very useful for stuff like this. For more info check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514750/how-to-format-date-displayed-in-datatable) out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to generate content for a cell.

For example:

```
'columns': [
   {
      'render': function(data, type, full, meta){
         if(type === 'display'){
            data = data.substr(0, 10);
         }

         return data;
      }
   }
]
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gL2haxty/1/) for code and demonstration.